# nested route on react when serving with iis

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router-dom

I serve react SPA through IIS. (uploaded build results in specific directory)

Accessing url `http://example.com/About` directly or refresh returned 404 error, so I figured out to add `web.config` like below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <rewrite> 
            <rules> 
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true"> 
                    <match url="(.*)" /> 
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" /> 
                </rule> 
            </rules> 
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Previous problem is solved, but I still cannot access nested urls like `http://example.com/directory/page1` directly. (Page does not return any error codes, just blank!)

Are there any missing points?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rewrite rule only rewrite url which uri is api. So I think `http://example.com/directory/page1` will not be affected. What's  the status code and substatus code in browser? Use [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to check if the url be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and eventually realized that the `web.config` is good, but the problem were the relative paths to JS bundles in my `index.html`.

For example, a script tag in your `index.html` might be something like:

```
<script defer="defer" src="app.js"></script>
```

If you visit `http://example.com/directory/page1`, IIS actually returns your `index.html` but the HTML contains relative src paths, so it tries to load the JS bundle at `http://example.com/directory/app.js`, which does not exist.

I fixed the issue by setting the output public path in my webpack config `output: { publicPath: '/' }` which makes the src an absolute path:

```
<script defer="defer" src="/app.js"></script>
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath